# Remote backup of /root directory

Tags: ssh, rsnapshot, backup

I'm setting up a server to do remote backups through SSH (pull). How can I copy the `/root` directory without logging in as `root` user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your backup user to a completely new group created for this purpose, and make that group the group-owner of everything under /root

```
chgrp -R newgroup /root
```

**or** make a small script that tars up /root to STDOUT (say, /usr/local/bin/tar-up-root) and configure your sudoers to allow your backup user to run the script passwordless:

```
backupuser  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/tar-up-root
```

and then

```
ssh backupuser@host-to-backup "/usr/local/bin/tar-up-root" > /var/tmp/remote-root-backup.tar
```

**or** run a script from cron, as root, on the host to be backed up, which tars up root to a file owned by the backup user and mode 600 (you don't want anyone else to be able to read this tarfile, or you've weakened security on /root), then have backupuser just scp this file off the host to be backed up.

Any of those any good?

Comment: Thanks for the advices, will probably use all of them for different problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your backup user to the wheel group, and it will have root privileges. Or add it to a less privileged group and give that group read access to the /root directory and all the files in it.

Comment: Not to raise a stink, but what makes you think that wheel group membership automatically grants such powers?

Comment: There is no `wheel` group by default in Ubuntu